# Trouble parsing an XML file with a compiled XPATH expression?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I was working through [a tutorial](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~dwss111/wiki.files/XML/xpathjava.pdf) and ran across an issue that I expected would work. I am hoping someone can help me with this code.  I can't get past this.   This code I shared below will match if I use the XPATH expression "**//*/text()**"  but it fails to match when I get more specific than that and use "**//tag0:G/text()**" .   Any idea what I am doing wrong?  I am just trying to get the 2 "tag0:G" values out of the XML that is also provided below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;    
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;    
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;    
public class Test1 {        
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Test start...");
    String myXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
    "<soapenv:Body>" +
    "<tag0:getA xmlns:tag0=\"http://me.ws.ix\">" +
    "<tag0:B>" +
    "<tag0:CC>" +
    "<tag0:CC>" +
    "<tag0:D>false</tag0:D>" +
    "<tag0:E>false</tag0:E>" +
    "<tag0:F xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nil=\"true\"/>" +
    "<tag0:G>10001</tag0:G>" +
    "<tag0:H>7744000002</tag0:H>" +
    "</tag0:CC>" +
    "<tag0:CC>" +
    "<tag0:D>false</tag0:D>" +
    "<tag0:E>false</tag0:E>" +
    "<tag0:F xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nil=\"true\"/>" +
    "<tag0:G>20002</tag0:G>" +
    "<tag0:H>1111122222</tag0:H>" +
    "</tag0:CC>" +
    "</tag0:CC>" +
    "<tag0:I>2012-05-27 23:38:48</tag0:I>" +
    "</tag0:B>" +
    "</tag0:getA>" +
    "</soapenv:Body>" +
    "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = null;
    NodeList nodes = null;
    try {           
      doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( myXML) ) );
      XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
        .compile("//tag0:G/text()"); // this fails, I don't know why
      nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Nodes length: " + nodes.getLength() );
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) { 
      String val = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue(); 
      System.out.println( "Val: " + val ); 
    }
    System.out.println("Test end...");
  }    
}
```

Comment: Insufficient information provided to answer. Fails how? 'More specific' such as what?

Comment: I provided a fully working code snippet that demonstrates the problem.  How is that insufficient?

Comment: If you run the code you will notice there is no stack trace.  This question is not about an error, its about xpath not matching something I expected it to match.

Comment: @djangofan Expecting people to run your code is wildly optimistic. You should provide enough detail so that an experienced enough reader can see the problem.

Comment: If something fails you should say HOW it fails. When we diagnose problems, the first thing we look at is the error message (or if it's incorrect results, we look at the incorrect results.) Downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you get on to compile an XPath expression, you should register a **[`NamespaceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29)** on your `XPath` instance. You do it using   [`XPath#setNamespaceContext(NamespaceContex nsContext`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29).

Please read [using NamespaceContext chapter](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html#namespacecontext) over at xml.apache.org.

The idea is that while your document was parsed with the namespace information, the XPath executor needs to know how to match the prefix you're using with the namespace URI in the document you run it on. The prefix itself says nothing and you can use any arbitrary prefix as long as it maps to the same URI.

p.s. here's more ore on [Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying.   I am still learning.  Thanks.  Why did the wildcard expression work though?  That threw me off.

Comment: this is different. by making your DOM factory namespaces aware you ensure your parsing will preserve namespace information. You now need to also tell your XPath what your prefix means. Please follow the links I provided and it should start making more sense. let me know if you still have questions

Comment: @djangofan, we all are learning every day. the wildcard worked because the `*` in XPath matches any element. It doesn't care all that much about the actual namespace of the elements since it is as good as any other for the `*` expression.

Comment: It turned out to be pretty easy and it makes a lot of sense now.  It is nice to finally sorta understand XML namespaces (at least I think I do).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could also cheat - if every occurence of "G" (or whatever element you are after) are from the same namespace - you can simply do

```
//*[local-name()='G']
```

However whilst this works this is just circumventing the issue. You might as well just bite the bullet and get across namespaces...